TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')
how u doing?
I´m using this PHP validation below to send a http response to a javascript function, but I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')".
Can anyone help me with to identify where should I change to fix this type error?
PHP
    if(!$validate_status) {
      header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 400 Bad Request");
    } else {
      header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"]." 200 OK");
    }

Javascript
function validate_submit(thisForm, action, formData) {
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    })
    .then(response => {
      if( response.ok ) {
        thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
        thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
        thisForm.reset();         
      } else {
        throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText} ${response.url}`); 
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
      if (data.trim() == 'OK') {
        thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
        thisForm.reset(); 
      } else {
        throw new Error(data ? data : 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      displayError(thisForm, error);
    });
  }

I tried to debug with chrome dev tools, but with no success. I couldn't find out why data content sent from php is undefined and I don't know how to fix it.

Your PHP snippet only sends the HTTP header without any content.

In the .then(data => {... part, data is undefined, because nothing is returned from the then above it. You probably need to return response.text(); after doing thisForm.reset();

Add return response.text(); in your first promise

You aren't returning anything from the promise chain before trying to access the data. Presumably, you meant to return the response's text?
function validate_submit(thisForm, action, formData) {
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: {'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'}
    })
    .then(response => {
      if( response.ok ) {
        thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
        thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
        thisForm.reset();
        return response.text(); // Here         
      } else {
        throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText} ${response.url}`); 
      }
    })
    .then(data => {
      thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
      if (data.trim() == 'OK') {
        thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
        thisForm.reset(); 
      } else {
        throw new Error(data ? data : 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action);
      }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      displayError(thisForm, error);
    });
  }


That's right, I'm trying to return and validate the statusText when is OK, but even when I fixed the code to return response.text() it didn't work. Now it directs to throw message error expected in the code "Form submission failed and no error message returned...".
I googled for best solutions about how to validate this, but I still didn't find.
Anyone knows any other solution for this?
